# Is there any way to flip an NSRulerView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

So i've been working with an NSRulerView, displaying line numbers. I'm currently in the process of displaying NoodleLineNumberView, however, when I display the line numbers and NSTextView, they're upside down.

[The cursor continues to move down as the numbers rise up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpPAJ.png)

Also, when I display this code:

```
if(lineNumberView.flipped == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"NSRulerView is flipped");
}
```

"NSRulerView is flipped" is logged.

Does anybody have a solution to my problem? Ask any questions if needed so.

[This is the link to the NoodleLineNumberView code](https://github.com/JanX2/NoodleKit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the answer, and I'm surprised that this isn't anywhere else. In order to flip the direction, add this to your NSRulerView subclass.

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped 
{
    return YES; // or NO depending on direction.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting it flipped is the correct answer but it should automatically follow the flipped setting of its parent. This is documented under the 'flipped' method for NSRulerView and works for me (I'm using Noodle's version of Apple's line numbering code too).